# How to print sentences with specific words

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get 3 most frequent words out of string and print sentences which include those words. Currently I found a lot of information about how to get most frequent words in string, however I'm stuck with getting only 3 of them and how to print sentences which include them.
Currently I'm in this state:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
var text = '<pre>'This is a sentence with few words in it. Repeated things. This is a sentence with words that are repeated. I don't need this text.';

var wordRegExp = /\w+(?:'\w{1,2})?/g;
var words = {};
var matches;
while ((matches = wordRegExp.exec(text)) != null)
{
    var word = matches[0].toLowerCase();
    if (typeof words[word] == "undefined")
    {
        words[word] = 1;
    }
else
{
    words[word]++;
}
}

var wordList = [];
for (var word in words)
{
if (words.hasOwnProperty(word))
{
    wordList.push([word, words[word]]);
}
}

wordList.sort(function(a, b) { return b[1] - a[1]; });

var n = 100;
var message = ["The top words are:"];
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
if (wordList[i][0].length>=5){
message.push(wordList[i][0] + " - " + wordList[i][1] + " occurance" +
            (wordList[i][1] == 1 ? "" : "s"));      

document.write(wordList[i][0] + "<br />");
}
}

alert(message.join("\n"));


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I' using 
     `if (wordList[i][0].length>=5)`
to avoid conjunctions, because most of them are made of 3-4 letters.

I should get answer like this:

```
'This is a sentence with few words in it. Repeated things. This is a sentence with words that are repeated.'
```

Because 3 most repeated words would be: "sentence" "repeated" and "words".
Do you have any idea how to achieve this? 
Some guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "word" and why do you add this optional group to your pattern: `(?:'\w{1,2})?`?

Comment: To match the most amount possible. 
Is that not needed?
By word I mean all lower cased A-Z words.

Comment: is it for things like: `don't`, `doesn't`, `isn't`, etc.? Do you want to take them as a single word?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 
I do want to include them as a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example where I focused on clarity rather than performance:

[**FIDDLE DEMO (corrected to top 3 rather than 2)**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmzjuydd/)

```
var text = "This is a sentence with few words in it. Repeated things. This is a sentence with words that are repeated. I don't need this text.";

var top3Words = topWordsIn(text, 3); //["sentence", "words"]

function topWordsIn(str, top) {
    var occurences = wordsOccurence(str),
        outConjuctions = function (word) { return word.length > 4; },
        byOccurenceDesc = function (a, b) { return occurences[b] - occurences[a]; };

    return Object.keys(occurences)
       .filter(outConjuctions)
       .sort(byOccurenceDesc)
       .slice(0, top || void(0));
}

function wordsOccurence(str) {
    var occurences = {};

    forWordsIn(str, function (word) {
        if (occurences[word]) ++occurences[word];
        else occurences[word] = 1;
    });

    return occurences;
}

function forWordsIn(str, cb) {
    var rx = /\b\w+\b/g, match;

    while (match = rx.exec(str)) cb(match[0].toLowerCase());
}
```

Then, once you have top words, you can simply tokenize your string into sentences (I just splitted on dots here), and filter out sentences that do not contain top words.

```
text.split(/\./).filter(function (sentence) {
    var topWordsRx = new RegExp('\\b(' + top2Words.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i');

    return topWordsRx.test(sentence);
});
//["This is a sentence with few words in it", " This is a sentence with words that are repeated"]
```

Note that you could make the algorithm more efficient by keeping track to which sentence the word belongs during the words tokenization process.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me and will guide me further!

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help! Splitting the work into many understandable functions makes the task much more easier to understand as well, keep that in mind.